# Passing Objects In RestSharp

Tags: c#, json.net, restsharp

I figure I have to be doing something obviously incorrect in my .NET code but I cannot figure out the issue.

I have two applications talking via RestSharp calls and, no matter what I attempt, the POST value coming from one application to another is ALWAYS NULL.  Here is my sending code:

```
            var client = new RestClient(_context.CloudUrl + ":" + _context.CloudPort.ToString() + "/api/web/AddRegisteredLocation");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myLocation, Formatting.None), ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I have tried .AddObject, .AddJsonBody, .AddBody - not using NewtonSoft.Json and even passing XML but this method always receives a NULL value:

```
    [Route("AddRegisteredLocation")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddRegisteredLocation([FromBody] string NewStringLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            RegisteredLocation newLocation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RegisteredLocation>(NewStringLocation);
            await _Manager.AddRegisteredLocation(newLocation);

            return new OkObjectResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            eventWriter.WriteEntry("AddRegisteredLocation failed with the exception: " + exc.ToString(), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
```

I have also tried this method:

```
    //POST: api/web/AddRegisteredLocation
    [Route("AddRegisteredLocation")]
    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddRegisteredLocation([FromBody] RegisteredLocation NewLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            await _Manager.AddRegisteredLocation(NewLocation);

            return new OkObjectResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            eventWriter.WriteEntry("AddRegisteredLocation failed with the exception: " + exc.ToString(), System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
```

And I have dropped the [FromBody] tag - nothing is working.  When I walk the code, the incoming value is ALWAYS Null.

If I use a Postman script and send in raw JSON through a POST request, that works fine so it has to be something on the Request side but I cannot figure it out.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: At first I would try to separate the URL in the two parts (_context.CloudUrl:port/_) in the RestClient constructor and the _web/AddRegisteredLocation_ path in the Request constructor and use _AddJsonBody_

Comment: That was my original format but I read another post on adding the serialized JSON object as a string in the Body - hence the changes.  I tried AddObject, AddBody, AddJsonBody but with the inline Request parameters (var request = new RestRequest("/api/web/AddRegisteredLOcation", Method.POST, DataFormat.Json);) and as constructed above.

Comment: Somebody mentioned that my service might be passing out JsonStrings and not JSONObjects which could be causing the issue but I do not know how to force one over the other.

Comment: I figured out, using Postman, that I have to drop the BsonId from the JSON in order for it to serialize.  I attempted to use BSON Reader/Writer but that fails because I cannot seem to pass the BSON string into the target method no mater what I try.

Comment: I suggest you to post an answer to explain what happened. It could be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the Bson ObjectId was the culprit - for some reason none of the serializers can handle it.  There is a BsonWriter and BsonReader options but both of those essentially use Base64-encoding which is slow and bloats messages.

To quickly overcome the issue, I ended up writing a set of classes without the BsonId and then a bunch of methods that manually copy the data from the MongoDB-based classes to the "serialization-friendly" classes.

This worked perfectly and, on the other end, the lack of an Object ID does not cause any issues with MongoDB.  I simply look the object up by a unique string name and assign the ID before making any changes.

This is probably NOT the most elegant solution but it does work!